# Simple C program error

Tags: c, arrays, element, combinations

I can't find any errors here. The purpose of the program is to thing all possible combinations of array elements and their sums. I'm trying to write a program which will return me an array of elements where every next one does not equal any previous one or the sum of any previous combinations of elements. I started like this and encountered an error: it says that program has stopped working...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int m[20];

void initm(int x[]) {
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        m[i]=i;
    }
}

void sorter(int x[]) {
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<20; j++) {
            /* nested for loop to get all possible combinations */
            printf("%d===%d===%d", x[i], x[j], x[i]+x[j]);  
        }
    }  
}

int main() {
    initm(m[20]);
    sorter(m[20]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"I can't find any errors here"` Did you look at your compiler's output messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m[20]` reads an `int` one element beyond the end of your array so

```
initm(m[20]);
sorter(m[20]);
```

should be

```
initm(m);
sorter(m);
```

Comment: Which means that there are probably a number of compiler warnings that the OP ignored.